# Method body is duplicating, only signature is changing

Tags: java, interface

I have generated objects with `wsimport` from WSDL definition.

In my main class, I just declare manually the endpoints I need, and pass it the PK to make the call.

I have to set up a HTTPS connection with a client PK. Thing is for each endpoint, I must set the `authenticateClient`. Bad thing is content is equal, just the signature is changing to another interface.

Isn't there a way not to duplicate the same method code again and again ?

```
private void authenticateClient(AdamConsultationMesuresServiceReadPortType port) {
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        SpringSoapClientConfig soapClientConfig = new SpringSoapClientConfig();
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = soapClientConfig.getKeyManagerFactory(company);
        TLSClientParameters tslClientParameters = httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters();
        if (tslClientParameters == null) {
            tslClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
        }
        tslClientParameters.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
        tslClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);
        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tslClientParameters);
    }

    private void authenticateClientCommandeCollectePublicationMesures(CommandeCollectePublicationMesuresPortType port) {
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        SpringSoapClientConfig soapClientConfig = new SpringSoapClientConfig();
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = soapClientConfig.getKeyManagerFactory(company);
        TLSClientParameters tslClientParameters = httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters();
        if (tslClientParameters == null) {
            tslClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
        }
        tslClientParameters.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
        tslClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);
        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tslClientParameters);
    }
```

Should I have define the input parameter as a Generic interface type or something like that ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but since it is a generated code, I would not bother about repetitions.

Comment: `authenticateClient` is not generated code, I have to add it myself :( wsimport generate all classes and interfaces that I will use. It can work this way, as I will have max 10 endpoints, it is no big deal. I'm no good at java, but it seems quite dirty to have 10 duplicated methods!

Comment: You can extract everything beneth  ` Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);` into some sort of `doYourStuffWithClient(Client client)`

Comment: Ask yourself - "how you would do it in Laravel" and do it the same way.

Comment: @Antoniossss hahaha ! Ok !

Comment: But big difference is there no mandatory types in PHP, so I could just forget the type, here is the issue

Comment: You have an example in my answer. Also you can use `Object` to forget the type but you wont be able to do much with it. After all, Java is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic and simplicit approach.

```
private void authenticateClient(AdamConsultationMesuresServiceReadPortType port) {
        doYourStuff(ClientProxy.getClient(port));
    }

private void authenticateClientCommandeCollectePublicationMesures(CommandeCollectePublicationMesuresPortType port) {
        doYourStuff(ClientProxy.getClient(port));
    }


private void doYourStuff(Client client){

    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    SpringSoapClientConfig soapClientConfig = new SpringSoapClientConfig();
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = soapClientConfig.getKeyManagerFactory(company);
    TLSClientParameters tslClientParameters = httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters();
    if (tslClientParameters == null) {
        tslClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
    }
    tslClientParameters.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
    tslClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tslClientParameters);

}
```

Comment: What shoud be the type of the Client ? I cannot find anything common between  interfaces

Comment: its `Client` as your code shows `Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port)`.  This is the same `Client` class. It should be imported already. IDE will help you out with it,.

Comment: ohhh, ok ! Let me check it !